# Xamarin Forms IOS - Access denied when trying to start process and run file

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, .net-core

I'm trying to run an external executable in Xamarin Forms.  I'm building this on a Mac using Visual Studio Code and/or Visual Studio for Mac.

No matter what I try, I get Access Denied as the file does not have the appropriate permissions ie, ideally should have 777 or something that allows the file to be invoked from Process.Start(filename).

When I include the file in a resources directory and define this as either a bundle resource or Content, the file gets packaged up and deployed to the simulator or iPhone, but the file permissions get changed so I can no longer execute and I receive the Access Denied message.

When I include the file as an Embedded resource, then write this file to the current directory at run time, I have the same problem as above and do not have the correct permissions on the file, so I receive the Access Denied message??

Need help to understand how I should package this file so that it deploys and I can execute in a process or is there a better way of running the executable.  I've tried many different versions of files here, a Mac compiled DLL, a Golang compiled Mac / Darwin exe, a x386 windows executable - all doing nothing than a simple print to console (to remove anything else that might be causing problems)....all have the same issue in that Xamarin seems to change the file permissions and get the Access Denied??

Please help?

Comment: You can execute native ABIs on Android but you can NOT do that on iOS. You would need to make it a static library or Framework and call its functions in-process

Comment: thanks, I don't have access to the original code in the executable I want to embed, so presume I would have the same problem in the static library?  Also, my code of choice is c# so will need some external help on this one I think.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: `I would have the same problem in the static library?` Yes, if you do not have source code, than that is a problem. If you do have the source/gain access to the source, assuming it is ObjC/Swift/C#/F# then you will have options at the point, otherwise you will have to write the functionality from scratch.